# Realizar consulta y mostrar en formulario HTML

Tags: php, mysql, relaciones

Tengo 3 tablas relacionadas en MySql,

tabla cliente:

id_cliente 
nombre_cliente
telefono_cliente
direccion_cliente
correo_cliente
nit_cliente 
dui_cliente 
nrf_cliente

Tabla factura

id_factura 
id_cliente
id_producto
fecha_facturas
cant_factura
subtotal_facturas
impuesto_facturas
percent_facturas
total_factura
deuda_factura
nota_factura

y lo que deseo es que la información de ambas tablas, especificamente los campos:

tabla cliente: nrf_cliente, nombre_cliente, telefono_cliente
tabla factura: fecha_factura, total_factura.

Se muestren en una tabla en html.

el codigo que tengo actualmente, pero no me muestra nada

````
        <thead class="table-dark alert-success">
            <tr>
                <th><i class="fa-solid fa-hashtag"></i> Codigo</th>
                <th><i class="fa-solid fa-user"></i> Nombre</th>
                <th><i class="fa-solid fa-user"></i> NRF</th>
                <th><i class="fa-solid fa-calendar-days"></i> Fecha de factura</th>
                <th><i class="fa-solid fa-phone"></i> Monto</th>
                <th><i class="fa-solid fa-gear"></i> Acciones</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <?php 
    
        include_once ("modulos/conexion.php");
    
        if(isset($_POST["buscarnombre"]))
        {
            $buscarnombre=$_POST["buscarnombre"];
    
            $sql_consulta= "SELECT * FROM cliente WHERE nombre_cliente like '%".$buscarnombre."%'";
        }
        else
    
    $sql_consulta= "SELECT id_factura, id_cliente, fecha_facturas, total_factura FROM factura INNER JOIN cliente ON factura.id_cliente = factura.id_cliente";
        
    
        if ($resultado=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql_consulta)) {
                while ($fila= mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
                    ?>
                <form method="POST">
<tr> 
<td><?php echo $fila["cliente.nombre_cliente"] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $fila["cliente.nrf_cliente"] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $fila["factura.fecha_factura"] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $fila["factura.total_factura"] ?></td>
<td>```
````

Comment: Si, perfectamente, y cual es el problema?

Comment: la consulta sería, ¿Como hacer el codigo php para ello ?

Comment: Hola Carlos, es necesario que nos muestres tu código para poder ayudarte, te sugiero que edites tu pregunta y lo agregues como texto.

Comment: Eso no es una pregunta.. es la definicion de un ejercicio.. que parte de ello no pudiste hacer??? hasta donde llegaste??? donde tuviste problemas???

Comment: mil disculpas, ya agregue el codigo hasta donde llevo la consulta. pero no me muestra el resultado

Comment: Creo que va con los nombres de las columnas que estas llamando, trata de hacer un echo de $fila para veas que te esta devolviendo y de ahi utilizas esas claves para mostrar los valores

Comment: no, no me muestra nada, aun habiendo realizado el echo de $fila

Comment: Revisa el log de php.